# Show that $\mathcal{B}$ - defined in the problem - is a basis for some topology on the set $X$. (Intersection and union of subsets)

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Say we have a set $X$. Say also that we have $\mathcal{C}$, a collection of subsets of $X$ whose union is equivalent to $X$.

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the collection of subsets of $X$ that are an intersection of (finitely) many elements of $\mathcal{C}$.

I'm trying to prove that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for some topology on the set $X$.

We know that a  basis for a topology on $X$ is a collection $A$ of subsets of $X$ (called basis elements) satisfying the following properties.

1. For each $x$ in $X$, there is at least one basis element $A$ containing $x$.
2. If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $A_1$ and $A_2$, then there is a basis element $A_3$ containing $x$ such that $A_3 \subset A_1 \cap A_2$.

For the first criterion, it seems clear that any $x$ in $X$ will be included in some subset element of $\mathcal{C}$ because $\mathcal{C}$'s elements have a union equal to $X$. I think that $\mathcal{B}$ will then possess an element that is some subset of $X$ that is an intersection of elements of $\mathcal{C}$ *and* contains the subset of $\mathcal{C}$ that contains $x$. Because our $x \in X$ was chosen arbitrarily, this is true for all $x \in X$.

For the second criterion, it seems like you could select two subsets in $\mathcal{C}$ that each contain $x$. Next, select a subset element of $\mathcal{B}$ that contains the common elements, including $x$. You then see that this third subset $B_3$ would belong in $\mathcal{B}$ because it is an intersection of smaller subsets of $X$ *and* that $B_3$ is a subset of the intersection of $B_1$ and $B_2$ because it contains the common elements of the two subsets.

I think my reasoning for the second criterion might be a bit flawed. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $x \in X$, it must be in some member of $\mathcal{C}$, say $x \in C$. This $C$ is in $\mathcal{B}$ too as $\cap \{C\}=C$ (a set is an intersection of a family of one and one is finite).

As to the second condition, you know that $A_1 = \bigcap_{i=1}^n C_i$ for some finite family $\{C_1,\ldots,C_n\}\subseteq \mathcal{C}$ and $A_2 = \bigcap_{i=1}^m C'_i$ for some other finite subfamily $\{C'_1, \ldots, C'_m\}$ of $\mathcal{C}$ and $x \in A_1 \cap A_2$. Now define $A_3 = \bigcap\{C_1, \ldots C_n, C'_1, \ldots, C'_m\}$ which is in $\mathcal{B}$, as the intersection of a finite subfamily of $\mathcal{C}$ ($n+m$ is still finite) and this $A_3$ is trivially as required: $x \in A_3 = A_1 \cap A_2 \subseteq A_1 \cap A_2$ etc.

You see how the fact that the family $\mathcal{B}$ being closed under binary intersections, makes the second condition quite easy.